# In MS Project, how do I create a task to start with the earliest of two dependencies?

Tags: ms-project

I have two tasks in Project: let's say task A's start is 1/30 and task B's start is 1/25 (end dates don't matter here).

I need to create task C, which starts at the earliest possible time - in this case, 1/25. However, I need to have this be an active link, because if B gets delayed - say to 2/15, the new earliest possible date is 1/30.

Doing 2 SS dependencies gives me the latest of the two dates - is there a way to get the earliest instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is not elegant and maybe not the best solution, but make two identical successor tasks and link one to A and the other to B.  Load 1/2 the resources in each task to the BAC is right.  Then, when you start C, nullify the unstarted tasks and load up the resources on the started one.

Answer (score 1):

Group A & B under a Summary task and then link C to the Summary with a Start-Start dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Colleen - there is no automated way of doing this.  I'm guessing Task A and B have different predecessors that are driving the different start dates?  You could link C Finish to Start with both predecessors and then remove the link to the second, once the earlier of the two is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this problem which whilst a little inelegant works like a dream.

Create a subsection at the end of your plan and out-dent it as far as possible  - I called subsection Earliest Date.

Within this section add (out-dented) milestones linked to the appropriate summary tasks from which you require to find the earliest date using Start to Start logic.

The summary task can then be used to drive your earliest dependencies by means of (again) Start to Start logic.

Answer (score 0):

Intriguing answers!   I find the "Subsection Earliest Date" to be the most practical----although they go against the traditional "don't link summary tasks".  Finally--a good reason to rebuff those who say that there is no use for links to summaries

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).